# Проверка ввода через getchar c использованием isdigit на отсутствие букв

Tags: c

Возможно ли сделать проверку ввода через getchar c использованием `isdigit`?

Чтобы при вводе символа, например вот так: `4t`, нужно было бы повторить ввод, пока все символы не будут только цифрами, т.е. не введены буквы.

```c
int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   char sum_num;

   // input number of elements
   printf("Enter numbers: ");
   //
   do{
      sum_num = getchar();
      if (!isdigit(sum_num)) printf("Sorry");
      } while(!isdigit(sum_num));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Чтобы при вводе буквы или символа или вот так "4t' нужно было повторить ввод. Пока это не будет число

Comment: Так а вы пробовали заменить условие в `while` на `isdigit(sum_num)`?